# PHP sync array keys

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Lets say that we have dynamically generated array.

```
    $arr[1]["a"] = "value";
    $arr[1]["b"] = "value";
    $arr[1]["c"] = "value";

    $arr[2]["a"] = "value";
    $arr[2]["b"] = "value";
    $arr[2]["c"] = "value";
    $arr[2]["d"] = "value";

    $arr[3]["a"] = "value";
    $arr[3]["g"] = "value";
```

Generating the Array can be manipulated, so do not take this example like a core lines.
As you see there is different keys, but at the end we must get:

```
$arr[1]['a'] = 'value';
$arr[1]['b'] = 'value';
$arr[1]['c'] = 'value';
$arr[1]['d'] = 'empty value';
$arr[1]['g'] = 'empty value';

$arr[2]['a'] = 'value';
$arr[2]['b'] = 'value';
$arr[2]['c'] = 'value';
$arr[2]['d'] = 'value';
$arr[2]['g'] = 'empty value';

$arr[3]['a'] = 'value';
$arr[3]['b'] = 'empty value';
$arr[3]['c'] = 'empty value';
$arr[3]['d'] = 'empty value';
$arr[3]['g'] = 'value';
```

non empty values are different, so array_merge is not so using good idea.

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: ok my bad, question is how to sync array keys as you see in example

Comment: What exactly you mean by `sync` is not really clear .....

Comment: at the begining of array you do not know how many keys you have.

Comment: it is two dimensional array first dimension is not important but on second one you have different array keys. the array will be used to generate csv file, so before generating it array must be like table.
all array keys in second dimension must be sync with others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this (this is horribly inefficient but my brain is struggling)

```
$keys = array();
foreach($arr as $array){
   $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($array));
}
//$keys now has all unique keys
foreach($arr as $array){
   foreach($keys as $key){
      if(!isset($array[$key])){$array[$key] = null}
   }
}
```

This is untested but i think it should work

Comment: indeed this looks like the only way. I was just curios if there is some tricky way to do this. tnx for your time

Answer (score 0):

I Guess is you want to fill your array with default values ... you can use `array_fill` to do that

```
$keys = array("a","b","c","d","g");
$arr[1] = array_combine($keys,array_fill(0, 5, 'empty value'));


$arr[1]["a"] = "value";
$arr[1]["b"] = "value";
$arr[1]["c"] = "value";


print_r($arr[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [a] => value
    [b] => value
    [c] => value
    [d] => empty value
    [g] => empty value
)
```

Comment: you do not know keys at the begining
array("a","b","c","d","g"); - nope
there is no info about key names and how many they are

this was the reason to give such example.
i will prepare one example ;)

Comment: Then how did you get `$arr[1]['d']` and `$arr[1]['g']` at the end

Comment: Baba there are 2 examples at my question
first one shows what we have and the second what we want
as I was typed in the question
there is little text "but at the end we must get:"
so how I get $arr[1]['d'] and $arr[1]['g']
guess how. Please next time read before vote or ask
thank you for your time